# mysqld_safe prohibits starting an instance from php

Tags: php, mysql

After looking as much as I could all over google and not finding anything relevant, here I am, asking you for some help.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to start/stop/report mysqld_multi instances directly from PHP. Everything works fine. I can stop an instance by giving his ID like this:

```
shell_exec("mysqld_multi ".$this::CONNECTSTRING." stop ".$instance."");
```

I can also get a report without any issues, but It won't start any instance. It doesn't let me start any instance.

```
shell_exec("mysqld_multi ".$this::CONNECTSTRING." start ".$instance."");
```

The instance just stays stopped and I have to start it directly from the terminal.

I tried to run with "--verbose" and I've got this warning:

```
"WARNING: mysqld_safe is being used to start mysqld. In this case you     may need to pass

"ledir=..." under groups [mysqldN] to mysqld_safe in order to find the actual mysqld binary.

ledir (library executable directory) should be the path to the wanted mysqld binary."
```

TL:DR: Can start an instance from the terminal but not from PHP. Can stop and get a report from PHP. Using "mysqld_multi"(because using multiple mysql instances)

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: Just curious is there a reason you are not using PHP's `mysqli_*` or `PDO` interface to do this?

Comment: The company where I work stil uses the old "mysql" not even mysqli...:( They never updated so we're stuck there with that "mysql".

Comment: And PDO can't stop or even start a mysql instance. If you can do that, can you give me a documentation link ? Thank you :)